# aws-sdk-php v2 で キーペア無しで EC2 Role を利用してS3アクセスする方法

Tags: php, aws, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, fuelphp

EC2 上で aws_sdk_ruby を使って

Aws::S3::Client.new

で引数をつけないで S3 クライアントを作成した ruby プログラムは
自動的に EC2 Role の権限によって動くようなのですが
(EC2 に S3Full をつけたりはずしたりすると動いたり動かなかったりする）

Fuel 上の aws-sdk-php を使って同様にキーペアを渡さずにかいたプログラムが
EC2 Role に関係なく AccessDeny になります

```
use \Aws\S3\S3Client;

            $s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
//              "key"    => Config::get("s3.$key.key"),
//              "secret" => Config::get("s3.$key.secret"),
                "region" => Config::get("s3.$key.region")
            ));

            $s3->putObject(array(
                "Bucket" => $bucket,
                "Key"    => "$prefix$path",
                "Body"   => $contents
            ));
```

コメントアウトをはずしてキーペアを明示的に渡せば動作します

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/docs/guide/credentials.rst
によると

```
use Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

// Use the default credential provider
$provider = CredentialProvider::defaultProvider();

// Pass the provider to the client.
$client = new S3Client([
    'region'      => 'us-west-2',
    'version'     => '2006-03-01',
    'credentials' => $provider
]);
```

という書き方ができるらしいのですが
`Class 'Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider' not found`
というエラーになってしまいます

aws-sdk-php 2.8.x-dev が入っているんですがこのバージョンでは使えない書き方なんでしょうか
aws-sdk を使ってる場所が多くてバージョンを変えると問題が出そうなので
このバージョンで EC2Role の権限を使うにはどうしたらいいでしょうか

Comment: 新規にインスタンスをたて、aws-php-sdk v2.8.xで冒頭に掲載のfactoryコード(コメントアウトのまま)で `$result = $client->listBuckets();`をしてみたところ正常にIAM Roleが使われているようでした。設定しているRoleに適切な権限が設定されていなかったりしませんか？(rubyのだとうごく、とは同じインスタンスでおなじバケットを操作しているかんじなのでしょうか)

Comment: 結局原因はわからず v3 にあげたところ引数無しで動作するようになりました。可能性の１つとしては別のコントローラーでキーペアを設定して s3 クライアントを作った後に、別のコントローラーで引数なしで作成した場合は直前の設定が使われてしまったりするのでしょうか…